# Lua Performance Loss - Clear Table

Tags: lua

A little background info: I am creating an infinite world generator with Lua.
When the player moves right, new tiles appear to the right and the tiles out of sight (left) disappear. I set the left-most tiles to `{}` or `nil` (I have tried both) in order to remove them. When the player continues moving right, there is major performance loss. I am able to regain performance simply by setting the entire map table to `{}`

Consider for the following, **assume their methods are filled out. They are unimportant**:

```
world = {
    tiles = {}
}

-- make world.tiles a 2D array of tiles
function createWorld()
  -- ...
end

-- remove left-most tiles, add right-most tiles
function onMovesRight()
  -- ...
end

-- remove all tiles
function destroyWorld()
  -- ...
end
```

After doing some tests when seeing a major degrade in performance, I have the found the following to occur when removing all tiles:

## 1.  Does ***not*** recover performance:

```
function recover()
  destroyWorld()
  world.tiles = {}
  createWorld()
end
```

## 2. ***Recovers*** performance

```
function recover()
  destroyWorld()
  world = {
      tiles = {}
  }
  createWorld()
end
```

Why does the second method above recover my Lua program's performance, but not the first?

Comment: Probably you store references to unneeded cells inside `world`, but outside of `world.tiles`.

Comment: Adding on to what @EgorSkriptunoff said, you can use [Weak Tables](https://www.lua.org/pil/17.html) elsewhere in the world to help avoid this issue.